# Devise: Change "forgot password" email form error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise for an english/french application and have been translating the different views. On devise/passwords/new.html.erb I have a message that appears when a "wrong" email address is entered and the "Send me reset password instructions" button is pressed.

I get the following message if there is an @ missing:

[A picture of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bGya.png)

There a different message if there is a @ with nothing following, or a @ with nothing before.

This message or even type of message doesn't seem to appear elsewhere, which is odd. It doesn't seem to be defined in the following files:

en.yml: github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml

devise_helper.rb: github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

validatable.rb: github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb

I think the backend of the message is linked to the regex validating emails and I have no idea where the frontend comes from (keep in mind I'm a bit new to all this). If I can't translate the message, I'd like at least to be able to desactivate this message.

Comment: Perhaps the form helper email_field is user. Can you verify that?

Comment: Yes it is being used, do you know where it is defined? Anyway thanks for the info, this is the provenance of the message so I now know how to deactivate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a bit more research and the error message you are receiving seems to be triggered by the browser (you are probably using Chrome). In other words, Devise has nothing to do with it.

The email_field helper probably causes client-side validation from the browser. One option would be to use classic field helpers, such as text_field, or you can add novalidate to prevent client-side validation from the browser. In the last case you should add some own validation if you want some restrictions.

Personally I like simple_form a lot, this is how this problem is countered in simple_form: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/HTML5-Attributes

Or for a html example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-novalidate

Comment: That explains the surprise I had seeing a different error message today: http://i.imgur.com/RkivPpy.jpg . I had switched navigators without thinking about it (Chrome for the original message, Firefox for the new one).

Comment: Damn browsers, as if Rails doesn't have enough magic on its own already. :)